# Compound Poisson Process

Tags: r, statistics, poisson

My task is to simulate a compound Poisson process defined as:

[image]

where

[image]

is a Poisson process and Y_i are Gamma(shape,scale) distributed. This is my R code:

```
# parameter for Poisson distribution.
lambda = 1
# parameters for Gamma distribution.
shape = 7.5
scale = 1

comp.pois = function(t.max, lambda) {
  stopifnot(t.max >= 0 && t.max %% 1 == 0)
  # offset ns by 1 because first y is 0.
  # generate N(t), that is number of arrivals until time t.
  ns = cumsum(rpois(n = t.max, lambda = lambda)) + 1
  # generate gamma distributed random variables Y_i.
  ys = c(0, rgamma(n = max(ns), shape = shape, scale = scale))
  # generate all X(t) for t <= t.max.
  return(c(0, cumsum(x = ys[ns])))
}
```

Compute a random sample of X(10) and compare means and variances.

```
# sample size.
size = 1000
t = 10
# ts is a vector of sample values for X(10).
ts = sapply(1:size, function(i) comp.pois(t, lambda)[t])

# sample mean and variance:
(mean.s = mean(ts))
(var.s = var(ts))

# theoretical mean and variance:
(mean.t = lambda * t * shape * scale)
(var.t = (shape + 1) * shape * scale^2)
```

output:

```
> # sample:
> (mean.s = mean(ts))
[1] 63.38403

> (var.s = var(ts))
[1] 184.3264

> # theoretical:
> (mean.t = lambda * t * shape * scale)
[1] 75

> (var.t = (shape + 1) * shape * scale^2)
[1] 63.75
```

This variance is gigantic, but I cannot spot my mistake. Please help. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I used the following algorithm to generate the N(t). I don't know why it is supposed to be better. I took it from *Rizzo, Maria L. Statistical computing with R. CRC Press, 2007.* The mean is good, but the variance is even worse. I tried sampling from the Gamma distribution only once for the entire simulation (although I'm pretty sure this does not reflect the problem very well) and the mean was off by around 10-40 for t = 10. When resampling for every X(t) (which is what the following code does), the mean is very exact. As pointed out, the variance is horrifying. This is probably not a good solution, but I suppose it is as good as it gets.

```
lambda = 3
shape = 6
scale = 2
size = 10000
eps = 1e-8

t = 10

# with probability 1-eps, n or less gamma distributed random variables are needed.
n = qpois(1-eps, lambda = lambda * t)
# sample from the gamma distribution. Not sure if it's ok to use the same sample every time.
# with this, the mean is of by about 10%.
# ys = c(rgamma(n = n, shape = shape, scale = scale))

# the interarrival times are exponentially distributed with rate lambda.
pp.exp = function (t0) {
  # not sure how many Tn are needed :/
  Tn = rexp(1000, lambda)
  Sn = cumsum(Tn)
  return(min(which(Sn > t0)) - 1)
}

# generate N(t) which follow the poisson process.
ns = sapply(1:size, function (i) pp.exp(t))
# generate X(t) as in the problem description.
xs = sapply(ns, function (n) {
  ys = c(rgamma(n = n, shape = shape, scale = scale))
  sum(ys[1:n])
})
```

output (t=10) in this case:

```
> # compare mean and variance of 'size' samples of X(t) for verification.
> # sample:
> (mean.s = mean(xs))
[1] 359.864

> (var.s = var(xs))
[1] 4933.277

> # theoretical:
> (mean.t = lambda * t * shape * scale)
[1] 360

> (var.t = (shape + 1) * shape * scale^2)
[1] 168
```

Comment: You should comment your code better.  I mean... I can write a compound poisson process generator but it's not clear why you're doing some of the steps you're doing or what your variables are supposed to represent in some cases.

Comment: Also the approach seems odd since you're only using the output for time t - why do you give more output? The other output doesn't seem all that useful since sure you get the magnitude of the 'jumps' but you aren't keeping track of at which time (t) they occur so it's not all that useful.

Comment: So as far as I understood, the meaning of a Poisson process is that the difference N(t) - N(t - 1) is a Poisson distributed random variable. This is why I computed `ns` the way I did. The final output is just mean and variance of the random variable X(10), which is what the exercise I am working on requires. I don't understand what you mean by keeping track of the time t. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Note that N(t) - N(0) ~ Pois(t*lambda) fulfills the poisson process as well... you can get the sample of N(t) directly with a single poisson draw. Then use that to determine how many samples from the gamma you need to make and sum those up - which gives you the value of the compound poisson process at time t.

Comment: And actually if you're using iid gammas you could use a bit of theory to only make a single draw from a gamma to do your entire simulation.

Comment: Also note that there is no restriction that t (your t.max) be an integer for a true compound poisson process.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I tried to make some changes (see edit). I'm not happy with the solution, but I don't expect to understand anymore what is wrong with it. Thank you for your help. If you wish to post an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.